# How to save Google Earth data for offline viewing

Tags: google-earth

I need is to save an area of 300X300 Kilometers for offline viewing. When I disconnect the internet connection and open GE, the images don't load... I know that there is an option for this on mobile, but can this be done on Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used Google Earth - but iirc there is a Disk Caching feature which can be accessed and modified to your needs, once you have set the Cache Size, zoom into the area you want cached layer by layer, until fully zoomed, and that data should then remain available offline.

Go to Tools -> Cache -> Disk Cache Size, and modify the size to your needs.

Comment: If this comment has helped, please could you take the time to rate it. Many thanks.

Comment: You should try it yourself before posting

Comment: @RegisteredUser - based on your comment, does that mean it did or didn't work? It's not clear from your tone.

Comment: While it would be ideal for me to test this - neither was I at home or near a computer, as this was posted on my iPhone, but I took the time to post a potential solution to your problem, so some gratitude would be nice.

Comment: You should not spam the questions with untested solutions.